# Sitecore JSS Tracker service is not working - Goals are not triggered

Tags: jss, goals

I have configured the Sitecore 9.3 instance with Sitecore JSS. Deployed the default JSS App in react successfully. All JSS related pages, services are working. I have enabled the "JSS Tracker service" as per mentioned in https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/services/tracking.

When I use the Style guide page from default JSS installation, I can submit the Goal request using the Tracker service successfully. I tried this many times with different goals. I am getting the "ok" and 201 response.

But, any goal triggered using the Tracker service are not visible in Goals in Experience Profile.
I checked the logs, I don't see any error in Sitecore or XConnect websites.

Comment: Have you checked the database or indexes to see if the data is there?

Answer (score 1):

After some reading, I found the Solution.

I created certificates for my Tracker Service site and the Front End, Assigned that to the Sites. When communicated over the HTTPS, it worked and started showing the goals triggered in the Experience Analytics.

Lesson Learned: **Use HTTPS for the Sitecore and Front end sites.**